# Find dynamically created control

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm dynamically creating an HTML table filled with devex radio list controls and adding it to the page.

```
//Create the radio list
ASPxRadioButtonList radButt = new ASPxRadioButtonList();
radButt.ID = "audit-" + audType;

tableCell2.Controls.Add(radButt);
tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell2);
auditTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
```

This all works fine.
Now, inside of a callback, I want to grab that radio list and get its setting ... so I am trying this but keep getting NULL.

```
ASPxRadioButtonList audRad = (ASPxRadioButtonList)Page.FindControl("audit-" + audType);
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: The problem is, your program will never maintain the viewstate of a dynamically generated control on postback, instead you'll have to use Request["<id>"] to get your control's value, and generate the control over and over on postback. The other is to add it to the ViewState dynamically

Comment: @Aniket OP doesn't explicitly mentions a postback.

Comment: @Maarten but I bet he means it..

Comment: Postback or not, He lost me at `radButt`...

Comment: I'm actually in a Callback inside of a devex callback panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [Page.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) method doesn't search all controls on the page. It only searches the top layer of controls. You have to search through all controls on the page using [Page.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) and [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx), probably recursively.

Another point, do you mean to find the radiobutton in the postback, or in the same request? If you mean in the postback, than you have to regenerate the control in the postback as well, just like Aniket mentioned.

Comment: It's in a callback, not a full postback.

Answer (score 2):

According to Maarten's answer, here is a recursive FindControl solution directly picked from [our Master's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html) :

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
    if (root.ID == id)
    { 
        return root; 
    } 

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```